# Js-sdk work troubleless but Php-sdk 3.1.1 getUser() function return 0 sometimes

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Firstly I want to say I know little english.

I have seeking about this problem for 1 day. I found a lot similar article and I tried solutions but I could not solve problem.

Js-sdk working troubleless and I can capturing `/me` with `FB.api` but I want to capture /me on server side for registration because anyone can change user informations that getting from client side.

Sometimes $facebook->getUser() return zero, usually chrome but sometimes work without any problem so I can not find where is the problem ? and what is the solution ?

How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When getUser() returns 0, just redirect the user to the normal login url, and if they're  logged in correctly, then they should come back to your app and then getUser() should return the correct value.

Comment: I am redirecting to that returned from getLoginUrl() but I am still getting 0 when I am try to get userid with getUser(). :(

Comment: What is your p3p header set to?

Comment: I do not know p3p but I researched briefly. Do you mean something like that header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');.If you mean that why am I use p3p ? I do not use something like that.Should I use p3p? Can you give me knowlage? thanks.

Comment: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceOfP3PAndACompactPrivacyPolicy.aspx  This will fix many issues with IE.

Comment: I do not know that why redirect to facebook did not work when I tried but now I have been solve with try the redirect to facebook.I thing that I used to make usage mistake.Thanks you for helping @DMCS :)